# There is a "Template Path Hint" on Prestashop (Like Magento)?

Tags: magento, prestashop, helper

I was using Magento for some projects and now I'm using Prestashop, and I can't find out a "Template Hints Path" feature like Magento has.
There are a function like that on Prestahop? Or some module?
If not, do you know any helper to retrieve template path?

Thanks on advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

acosta

I've tried searching but could not find plugins or modules like, but perhaps a tutorial on Prestashop can be useful because there informed blocks name, id and folder:

link : [where the hooks and modules are](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS14/Coding+a+theme/#Codingatheme-Modules)

[image]

image : [Integration Home Blocks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQaUN.png)

[image]